# The selected div should not hover in the slideshow [JsFiddle]

Tags: html, css, hover, slide, checked

The selected (the one in the front) id that is checked in the slideshow should not hover, I dont know how to make it work? Check out the JsFiddle.

Googled and coulnt figure it out.

```
  /*sliderhover 1*/
   #slide1 { 
top: 50px;
background-color: darkred;
  }
#slide2 { 
top: 50px;

background-color: darkred;
}
#slide3{
top: 50px;
background-color: darkred;
}
#slide4 { 
   top: 50px;
background-color: darkred;
}
#slide5 { 
top: 50px;
background-color: darkred;
}
#slide1:hover {
top: 0px;
transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
}
#slide2:hover {
top: 0px;
transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
}
#slide3:hover { 
top: 0px;
transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
  }
#slide4:hover { 
top: 0px;
transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
}
 #slide5:hover {
top: 0px;
transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evwqL0cz/1/

If you hover over the main image in the front a bug will hapen in the buttom of the square. Therefore I need it to not hover.

Comment: Please do not make edits that are entirely redundant. You are willfully wasting reviewers' time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the javascript code to your existing code.

```js
function slidesBehind(){
  let selectedSlide = 
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)');
  selectedSlide.forEach(function (s, index) {
      let elemtId=s.id;
      let elm=elemtId.split('');
      elm[1]='slide'+elm[1];
      document.querySelector('#'+elm[1]).style.cssText = null;
 });
}

function slidefront(){
   let selectedSlide = 
   document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').id;
   let elm=selectedSlide.split('');
   elm[1]='slide'+elm[1];

   const elem = document.querySelector('#'+elm[1]);
   elem.style.top = "50px";
}
slidefront();
  
document.querySelector('#slider').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  slidesBehind();
  slidefront();
})
```

```css
#slider {
         color: white;
         height: 30%;
         position: relative;
         perspective: 900px;
         transform-style: preserve-3d;
         right:10%;
         margin-top:100px;
         height: 333px;
 }
.slidercontainer{
    position: absolute;
    padding-top:100px;
 }
#slider label {
         margin: auto;
         width: 45%;
         height: 63%;
         border-radius: 4px;
         position: absolute;
         left: 0; right: 0;
         cursor: pointer;
         transition: transform 0.4s ease;
       }
#s1:checked ~ #slide4, #s2:checked ~ #slide5,
#s3:checked ~ #slide1, #s4:checked ~ #slide2,
#s5:checked ~ #slide3 {
         box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
         transform: translate3d(-30%,0,-200px);
 }
#s1:checked ~ #slide5, #s2:checked ~ #slide1,
 #s3:checked ~ #slide2, #s4:checked ~ #slide3,
#s5:checked ~ #slide4 {
         box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
         transform: translate3d(-15%,0,-100px);
 }
#s1:checked ~ #slide1, #s2:checked ~ #slide2,
#s3:checked ~ #slide3, #s4:checked ~ #slide4,
#s5:checked ~ #slide5 {
         box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
         transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
#s1:checked ~ #slide2, #s2:checked ~ #slide3,
#s3:checked ~ #slide4, #s4:checked ~ #slide5,
#s5:checked ~ #slide1 {
         box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
         transform: translate3d(15%,0,-100px);
       }
#s1:checked ~ #slide3, #s2:checked ~ #slide4,
#s3:checked ~ #slide5, #s4:checked ~ #slide1,
#s5:checked ~ #slide2 {
         box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
         transform: translate3d(30%,0,-200px);
       }
       /* vinyl sliderhover 1*/
#slide1 { 
   top: 50px;
    background-color: darkred;
}
#slide2 { 
    top: 50px;
   
    background-color: darkred;
}
#slide3{
  top: 50px;
    background-color: darkred;
 }
#slide4 { 
    top: 50px;
    background-color: darkred;
 }
#slide5 { 
top: 50px;
   background-color: darkred;
}
#slide1:hover {
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }
#slide2:hover {
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }
#slide3:hover { 
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }
#slide4:hover { 
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }
#slide5:hover {
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }
```

```html
<section id="slider">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3" checked>
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5">
     <label for="s1" id="slide1">
         <div class="moveuponhover">
             <div class="vinylplay">
                 <a id="play-video" class="video-play-button"            
       href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('slide-content','Whew!            
      You clicked!')">
                  <span></span>
                  </a>
             <div id="video-overlay" class="video-overlay">
                  <a class="video-overlay-close">&times;</a>
             </div>
          </div>
            <img src=""  width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/>
        </div>
      </label>
      <label for="s2" id="slide2">
          <div class="moveuponhover">
               <div class="vinylplay">
                   <a id="play-video" class="video-play-button" href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('slide-content','Whew! You clicked!')">
                      <span></span>
                   </a>
               </div>
               <img src="images/Ambient/R-4538741-1367760456-3876.jpeg.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/>
            </div>           
       </label>
       <label for="s3" id="slide3">
          <div class="moveuponhover">
             <div class="vinylplay">
                  <a id="play-video" class="video-play-button" href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('slide-content','Whew! You clicked!')">
                      <span></span>
                  </a>
             </div>
                <img src="images/Ambient/hiroshiyoshimurawetlands.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/>
         </div>
      </label>
      <label for="s4" id="slide4">
             <div class="moveuponhover">
                 <div class="vinylplay">
                      <a id="play-video" class="video-play-button" href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('slide-content','Whew! You clicked!')">
                         <span></span>
                      </a>
                 </div>
                 <img src="images/Ambient/tumblr_p2i6l0MBWA1uvvamyo2_250.jpg" 
                    width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/></div></label>
       <label for="s5" id="slide5">
             <div class="moveuponhover">
                 <div class="vinylplay">
                      <a id="play-video" class="video-play-button" href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('slide-content','Whew! You clicked!')">
                          <span></span>
                      </a>
                 </div>
                 <img src="images/Ambient/pierloft.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/></div></label>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks alot naman! It works very well :) Here is an updated JsFiddle if some other find this topic useful :) - https://jsfiddle.net/0jfos6wL/

Comment: Though i cant seem to get it to work in my own website. I link to the Js in a separate file. I tried to link to it in the head and also buttom of the body. Still not working. Any idea how to make the code work on my site?

Comment: Seems it may work when i first update the site but when i click any of the slides the front one starts hovering again? Im not sure but i think this is what is hapening on my website when i implement the code.

Comment: Do you notice any JavaScript error in your console when you click on the slide.?

Comment: I will drop the link here for a while. - 

https://idekakel.000webhostapp.com/secretplace/secret%20place/index.html

Doesnt seem to be any Js error for the code that is used for the hover. Ignore one of them which says Nohover since that is not being used atm. As you may notice it works in the beging but not when one is clicked. Also one slide not working but it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Move                                                                                                              
"<script type="text/javascript" src="js/displaydivJS.js"></script>"                             Below your Jquery , If you check your console, it show's an error $ is not defined

Comment: Fixed, sorry for late respons. Now the jquery script link is in the top of the body and the link to your JS script is in the bottom of the body, else it wont work. Not sure why? But there is this error when you click on one of the slides. I think its the same error on the website i linked. (it refers to your script) ---


"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at FrontslideNohover.js:10
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at slidesBehind (FrontslideNohover.js:6)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (FrontslideNohover.js:26)"

Answer (score 0):

Remove ":hover" from whichever selected id you want.

ex: #slide2:hover{} becomes #slide2{}

Comment: The code is already like this, what should i change?

         #slide1 { 
          top: 50px;
          background-color: darkred;
          }

Comment: Try getting rid of all the different css stylings with:

 #slide1:hover {
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }

#slide3:hover { 
    top: 0px
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }
#slide4:hover { 
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }
#slide5:hover {
    top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0.1s;
 }

Basically just get rid of anything that has ":hover" following it.

Use this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3nkd7L82/

Comment: Yeah but then no one of the slides will hover. I want all to hover but the one in the front.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstoof the original question. I am not sure exactly how to solve this problem. I would try to implement some JS that indicates which specific label has been clicked (since that one will be upfront) and get the corresponding id for that label. Then with the id you can simply edit the css to disable the hover response on the clicked label.